# Adding values in mongoose model.findOneAndUpdate

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a cart route where I want to add the quantity of item with the same size.

Please take a look.

```
Cart.findOne({userPurchased: cartItem.userPurchased}, function(err, item){
    console.log(item);
    if(err) throw err;

    if(item){
        if(item.products.product === cartItem.products.product && item.products.size === cartItem.products.size){
            Cart.findOneAndUpdate({userPurchased: cartItem.userPurchased}, {$add: [products.quantity, cartItem.products.quantity]}, {new: true}, function(err, result){
                res.json(result);
            })
        } else {
            Cart.findOneAndUpdate({userPurchased: cartItem.userPurchased}, {$push: {products: cartItem.products}}, {new: true}, function(err, updated){
                if(err) throw err;

                res.json(updated);
            })
        }
    } else {
        Cart.create(cartItem, function(err, result){

            res.json(result);
        });
    }
});
```

At first, I am trying to find if there is a person that has a record already on the database. If it finds one, I will check if the item I am adding has already added by the user and if the size is the same. If the it is the same, then I will just update the quantity by adding the `products.quantity`(quantity from db) to `cartItem.products.quantity`(quantity from request body) using `$add` in mongoose. The problem here is that it gaves me an error **products is not defined** on the line where `$add` is located. ALSO, I don't know if this is the right implementation. Please enlighten me. Thank you so much.

Comment: `$add (aggregation)` only work in aggregation so you can use `Cart .aggregation([criteria,callback])`

Comment: any other approach on adding those two values?

Comment: Would be really great if you could [edit] your question to show your `Cart` model's schema definition, as well as an example `cartItem` object.